# 1980s movie about a handsome alien visiting Earth and meeting a woman

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

The story is about a handsome alien/man visiting from another planet. He meets a woman and helps her fight a gang. In the end, he dies at the hands of the gang and his spirit returns to his planet. It was a low-budget film. I believe it is set in Los Angeles, but I'm not sure, and I remember that the woman was an artist who lived in a warehouse type of building.

Comment: For the duration of the first 2 sentences, I was thinking "Earth Girls Are Easy."

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be [Alien Warrior (1986)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoMJSJkOI9Y)

Final scene ("spirit"):
[image]

Plot

> An alien from another dimension who is basically Space Jesus lands on
> earth to fight the "Great Evil" that has been unleashed on the urban
> wastelands of 80's Los Angeles. He builds a Ferrari out of junkyard
> parts and befriends drunks, street urchins, and hookers.